# Why I am getting error as I am trying to send a text to another page after getting it from a textfield.I am using bloc for this

Tags: flutter, bloc

Here is the error.I am trying to send a text to another page after getting it from a textfield.I am using bloc for this.

> I/flutter (28636): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
>   ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter
>   (28636): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
>   MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(360.0, I/flutter (28636): 672.0),
>   devicePixelRatio: 2.0, textScaleFactor: 1.0, platformBrightness:
>   Brightness.light, padding: I/flutter (28636): EdgeInsets.zero,
>   viewPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
>   physicalDepth: I/flutter (28636): 1.7976931348623157e+308,
>   alwaysUse24HourFormat: false, accessibleNavigation: false, I/flutter
>   (28636): disableAnimations: false, invertColors: false, boldText:
>   false)): I/flutter (28636): The getter 'state' was called on null.
>   I/flutter (28636): Receiver: null I/flutter (28636): Tried calling:
>   state I/flutter (28636): I/flutter (28636): User-created ancestor of
>   the error-causing widget was: I/flutter (28636):   Scaffold 
>   lib\main.dart:166 I/flutter (28636): I/flutter (28636): When the
>   exception was thrown, this was the stack: I/flutter (28636): #0
>   Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
>   I/flutter (28636): #1      _BlocBuilderBaseState.didUpdateWidget

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return BlocProvider(
    //   builder: (BuildContext context) => TextBloc(),
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Bloc Text',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      // ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String initialData = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
    //  final TextBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of<TextBloc>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar:
          AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.green[200], title: Text('Store Text')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.amber,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
              child: StreamBuilder(
                  initialData: initialData,
                  stream: bloc.textStream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : ''}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
              child: StreamBuilder(
                  initialData: initialData,
                  stream: bloc.textStream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                      _controller.text = snapshot.data;
                    return TextField(
                      controller: _controller,
                      onChanged: bloc.textChangedStream,
                      // decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter name' ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[100],
                        filled: true,
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 0.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 200,
              child: StreamBuilder(
                  initialData: initialData,
                  stream: bloc.textStream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Open Next Page'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute<SecondPage>(builder: (context) {
                          return BlocProvider.value(
                            //value: bloc,
                            child: SecondPage(),
                          );
                        }));
                      },
                    );
                  }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String initialData = '';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Page'),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder(
        builder: (context, text) {
          return Center(
            child: StreamBuilder(
                initialData: initialData,
                stream: bloc.textStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : ''}');
                }),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextBloc {
  final StreamController textStreamController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  Stream<String> get textStream => textStreamController.stream;
  Function(String) get textChangedStream => textStreamController.sink.add;
}

final TextBloc bloc = new TextBloc();
```

Comment: you need to provide the full stacktrace. This seems cut off right?

Comment: It gets solved when I remove BlocBuilder from SecondPage class.